# How to access dd-wrt bridge?

Tags: router, wireless-bridge, dd-wrt

I have installed dd-wrt on my fonera some months ago, then I configured it as wireless bridge and forgot about it, never used it again for some time.
Now I need it again in a different configuration, but I don't know how to access the configuration interface: if I connect it to the ethernet, it has no IP address of its own. It still works, but now it's just an open access point, which is not what I need.

How do I get to the configuration interface again?

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation with an old Linksys router that I converted into a bridge. With DD-WRT, you should be able to perform a [30-30-30 reset](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Reset_And_Reboot) to clear all configuration information:

1. Press and hold the router's reset button for 30 seconds.
2. While still holding the reset button, disconnect the power cord from the router. Leave it unplugged for 30 seconds.
3. Still holding the reset button, plug the power cord back into the router. Hold the reset button for another 30 seconds before releasing it.